# Python object initialisation performance

Tags: python

I was just doing some quick performance tests, and I noticed that initialising a list generically is about four to six times slower than explicitly (those are probably the wrong terms, I'm not sure on the lingo here). For example:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> print timeit.timeit('l = list()', number = 10000000)
1.66420578957
>>> print timeit.timeit('l = []',     number = 10000000)
0.448561906815
```

And similarly with tuples and ints:

```
>>> print timeit.timeit('l = tuple()', number = 10000000)
1.10791182518
>>> print timeit.timeit('l = ()',      number = 10000000)
0.23167181015

>>> print timeit.timeit('l = int()', number = 10000000)
1.3009660244
>>> print timeit.timeit('l = 0',     number = 10000000)
0.232784032822
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 8):

Using the [dis module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to inspect the bytecode:

```
import dis        
dis.dis(lambda: list())
```

yields

```
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

while

```
dis.dis(lambda: [])
```

yields

```
  7           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

So `list()` requires looking up a global name and calling the object, while `[]` does not.

Answer (score 2):

That's because using literal syntax, python knows to build the list with one bytecode. Calling the constructor requires looking up the `list` global and calling it instead:

```
>>> def foo(): []
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 POP_TOP             
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> def bar(): list()
... 
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 POP_TOP             
              7 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Different bytecodes. Taking `list()` vs `[]` as an example:

```
l = list():
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (l)

l = []:
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (l)
```

The former involves a name lookup for `"list"` and a function call.