# What's the difference between list() and []

Tags: python

What's the difference between the following code:

```
foo = list()
```

And

```
foo = []
```

Python suggests that there is one way of doing things but at times there seems to be more than one.

Comment: Other questions: `dict()` and `{}`, `tuple()` and `()`, etc.

Comment: Related: [Python object initialisation performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991248/python-object-initialisation-performance)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One is a function call, and the other is a literal:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f1(): return list()
... 
>>> def f2(): return []
... 
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(f2)
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Use the second form. It's more Pythonic, and it's probably faster (since it doesn't involve loading and calling a separate function).

Answer (score 30):

For the sake of completion, another thing to note is that `list((a,b,c))` will return `[a,b,c]`, whereas `[(a,b,c)]` will not unpack the tuple. This can be useful when you want to convert a tuple to a list. The reverse works too, `tuple([a,b,c])` returns `(a,b,c)`.

Edit: As orlp mentions, this works for any iterable, not just tuples.

Comment: I would argue this is the most important distinction, since it is the one that actually produces different results.

Comment: This holds for any iterable.

Comment: Another distinction is when you call both on the function map(). One will convert the object into a list while the other will simply wrap the object by [].

Answer (score 18):

`list` is a global name that may be overridden during runtime. `list()` calls that name.

`[]` is always a list literal.

Comment: Note that only terrible people override `list`. (It's a good point, though.) :P

Comment: @Doorknob: From the look of all the questions on SO where `list` (and `str` and `dict`) get used as variable names, I tend to agree. :)

Comment: @tckmn, terrible programmers :)