# How are lists created without the class name?

Tags: python, python-internals

It is possible to go about creating lists like this:

```
l = list()

l.append(1)
```

however the most common method is to create a list like this:

```
l = [1]
```

My question is simple in the concept but probably extremely complicated in the answer but how is it that the list is created with a notation outside the usual class notation?

I have looked through the source code at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c and cant find where it defines the list notation [].

I am not asking about the difference between [] and list() - I am asking why you can use [] at all. How is it possible that this object is created differently from other objects?

Comment: `list` is the name of the class, and also a builtin

Comment: yes but I want to know where in the python source code that it is defined to be created with the square brackets

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716401/whats-the-difference-between-list-and

Comment: im more asking about how one would go about defining a new data structure using notation that is different from the regular class notation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between list() and \[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716401/whats-the-difference-between-list-and)

Comment: It's part of the grammar: `atom: ... | '[' [testlist_comp] '] | ...`; it's not something you can define yourself *in* Python.

Comment: I think the definition of this notation should be somewhere in the parser: when it sees this particular syntax, it generates code to initialise a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list literal `[...]` is defined by the grammar, the same as keywords like `if` and `while`:

```
atom: ... | '[' [testlist_comp] '] | ...
```

When the code generator encounters a list literal in the AST, it generates a specific byte code to create a list:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('[]')
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

whereas a call to `list` is handled like any other callable:

```
>>> dis.dis('list()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

For non-empty lists, the expressions in the literal are added to the stack for `BUILD_LIST` to use:

```
>>> dis.dis('list([1,2])')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BUILD_LIST               2
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

A call like `list([1,2])` necessarily uses `BUILD_LIST` first to create a list before passing *that* to `list` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

`[1]` is a list-literal - it implicitly creates the `list()` with `1` in it (stores it in the heap). I'm sure you can find this if you dig around in the code-base a bit more.