# What's the difference between creating a list with "list()" and "[]" in Python?

Tags: python, list

I've always used 
`new_list = list()`
to create a list in Python 3 because I think it's more elegant, but is it any different than
`new_list = []`
?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716401/whats-the-difference-between-list-and

Answer (score 1):

`list()` will create `[]` so in the end, the result it is not different

---

from performance perspective `[]` is faster

```
%timeit list()
# 99.6 ns ± 0.871 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit []
# 36 ns ± 15.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: A theory on why the performance difference exists: ‘list’ needs to be looked up at runtime (it can be redefined) [] cannot.  Also points out potential difference.